# Radio button disable and enable depends on values angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I am trying to disable and enable radio button depends on values. In my code, if I enter "yes" in the text box then clicked ok button radio button one is disabled. But if I type no radio button 2 is not disabling. I do not know what is happening. Anyone can find the mistake in my code?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-button-gdpwvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
clickit(){

if(  this.entervalues=="yes" )  {
this.radio1=true;
}

 if(  this.entervalues=="no" )  {
this.radio2=true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have only 1 variable to save the value of radio button

Try this in html,

```
    <div class="form-check-inline">
       <label class="form-check-label">
       <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="radio" [(ngModel)]="radio1" [disabled]="disabled" [value]="true">Yes
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check-inline">
       <label class="form-check-label">
       <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="radio"  [(ngModel)]="radio1" [disabled]="!disabled" [value]="false">No  
       </label>
     </div>
```

and this in component.ts,

```
clickit(){
  if(  this.entervalues=="yes" )  {
   this.disabled=true;
  }

  if(  this.entervalues=="no" )  {
    this.disabled=false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes..but i could not the radio button..How to disable depends on values?

Comment: can you create a separate question for that?

Comment: No..Actually i am trying to achive this but i want to edit my question. So please answer it

Comment: Not working...initially both enable...if i entered "yes" yes radio button should be disable...If i enter "no"  no radio button should be disable  :https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-button-jzterc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Initially do not disable radio button "no" and "yes"

Comment: Are you there?i am waiting for your reply

Comment: This code is perfectly working. In your code change [disabled]="!disabled" in second input. I have tested. Sorry got to dash

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 variables:

```
  radio;
  entervalues;


  clickit(){
    this.radio = this.entervalues === "yes";
  }
```

And in template:

```
<label class="form-check-label">
     <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="radio"  [(ngModel)]="radio" [value]="true">Yes
</label> 
 ...
<label class="form-check-label">
     <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="radio"  [(ngModel)]="radio" [value]="false">No
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code.
basic issue is that you are setting `radio2` value to true in .ts, but in html attribute is bound to `false`. So, `radio2` will be selected if value of modal bounded to it is `false`.

[link for modified code (changed `radio2` to false on click if value in text box is no)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-button-qwetjg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)